# composite entities in story version of wit.ai

Tags: wit.ai

I am trying to familiarize myself with wit.ai story version using a pizza ordering example. As suggested, I used the start point as an all inclusive example:

"Hi I would like to order a large pan crust pepperoni pizza with medium fries and a small tomato juice and a bundt cake"

In the above example, I can see the need for below composite entities

- pizza:{type:pepperoni,size:large,crust:pan}
- sides:{type:fries,size:medium}
- drink:{type:juice,subType:tomato,size:small}
- dessert:{type:cake, subType: bundt}

How do I create a composite entity in the "Understanding" tab ?

thanks

venu

Answer (score 0):

Composite Entities are disabled in Stories for now. We are in the middle of an infrastructure update that should increase robustness considerably. This is a high pri item, so as soon as that lands, we will release composite entities in Stories.